# onChange not getting called on TextField change when binding comes through ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I create a simple `TextField` with an `@State` the `onChange` gets called.

But when I have an `$item` that comes from `ForEach` through a `list`, `onChange` is not called.

I have a working demo below (must be run on simulator/device and not just in preview).
The list changes and that can be verified by clicking the `print list` button. But for some reason the `onChange` modifier is not called when the data is changed.

When getting the `item` from the list with `index`, swiftui crashes (@main index out of bounds error) when the list changes.

Any idea how to get this to work without using `index` to access the `item`?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    @State var simple = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $simple)
            .onChange(of: simple) { newText in
                print("simpleChanged: \(newText)")
            }
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(Color.green)

            ForEach($viewModel.list, id:\.self) { $item in
                HStack {

                    TextField("", text: $item.text)
                    .onChange(of: item.text) { newText in
                        print("listChanged: \(newText)")
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("list:")
                for item in viewModel.list {
                    print(item.text)
                }
            }) {
                Text("print list")
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [TestModel] = [
        TestModel(index: 0, text: ""),
        TestModel(index: 1, text: ""),
        TestModel(index: 2, text: "")
    ]
}

struct TestModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var index: Int
    var text: String
}

@main
struct PrufurNoPodsApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = TestViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TestView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `.onChange(of: item)`?

Comment: Yes and gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by changing the `TestModel` from `struct` to `class`

```
class TestModelClass: ObservableObject, Hashable {
    @Published var text: String
    
    init(index: Int, text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self).hashValue)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: TestModelClass, rhs: TestModelClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs === rhs
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TestViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach($viewModel.list, id:\.self) { $item in
                TextField("", text: $item.text)
                .onChange(of: item.text) { newText in
                    print("listChanged: \(newText)")
                }
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .background(Color.gray)
           }
        }
    }
}


class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [TestModelClass] = [
        TestModelClass(index: 0, text: ""),
        TestModelClass(index: 1, text: ""),
        TestModelClass(index: 2, text: "")
    ]    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the onChange modifier is not called for the TextField when using $item from the ForEach loop is because the Binding created by the $item.text binding is not mutable. In other words, you cannot directly modify the value of $item.text within the onChange closure.

To work around this limitation, you can introduce a separate Binding variable within the ForEach loop to bind to the TextField and modify the corresponding TestModel object. Here's an updated version of your code that demonstrates this approach:

```
ForEach(viewModel.list.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    let binding = Binding<String>(
        get: { viewModel.list[index].text },
        set: { viewModel.list[index].text = $0 }
    )

    TextField("", text: binding)
        .onChange(of: binding.wrappedValue) { newText in
            print("listChanged: \(newText)")
        }
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .background(Color.gray)
}
```

In this modified code, the ForEach loop iterates over the indices of the viewModel.list array rather than the elements directly. Inside the loop, a new Binding called binding is created for each TestModel object.

The get closure of the binding retrieves the text property from the corresponding TestModel object, and the set closure is used to update the text property when the TextField value changes.

By using this separate binding variable, you ensure that the onChange closure is called when the TextField value changes, and you can correctly modify the TestModel object associated with that specific TextField.

Comment: I have seen `index out of bounds` error when using `list[index]` in a view on a dynamic list. So I am trying to find a solution that doesn't use indexing of the list.

Comment: And I don't see the point in creating this new binding, if you want to get the item from the list by using the index, why not just access it from the list directly and pass it as binding? Like so: $list[index] This is something I have tested and the onChange function is called correctly. But this is not usable since it makes swiftui crash (index out of bounds at @main func) when the list changes.